# Symfony2 Fatal error when dumping assets with assetic

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

when I dump my assets using the following command

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --watch
```

I receive this error

```
Fatal error: Method 
Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Factory\Resource\FileResource::__toString() 
must not throw an exception in 
vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Factory/Loader/CachedFormulaLoader.php on line 0
```

It doesn't happen when dumping using

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: I'd say `--watch` is not compatible with dumping. Consider creating a bugreport as you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's not a `--watch` compatibility matter because it worked well few days ago as indicated in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment). I just can't figure out what has changed in my environement or in my conf that broke it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback, my note was more or less quickly written. The error you see `__toString() 
must not throw an exception` is relativly hard to track because standard PHP debugging mechanisms don't work well here. If you can run that command within xdebug (or some other debugger) and take a look what causes the exception that would be great.

Comment: My first guess was on permission matter cause of `line 0` but  changing the permission didn't bring it back.

Comment: @vassr: The stack you can give is shortened because the originating point of the exception that is thrown inside `__toString()` is hidden.